# Duda sobre declaracion e inicialización de un Array

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un par de dudas con respecto a la declaracion e inicialización de arrays.

```
Private mat()() As Integer
Private mat2(,) As Integer

Public Sub Prueba()
    ReDim mat2(2, 4)
    ReDim mat((4)()) //Error
    mat = New Integer(1)() //Error
    mat = New Integer(1)() {}
    mat2 = New Integer(4, 2) //Error
    mat2 = New Integer(4, 2) {}
End Sub
```

Basicamente me gustaría saber por qué dan error esos 3. Porque no puedo usar ReDim en un array irregular?
El 2 y 3 error supongo que son iguales, por qué no tiran error cuando uso los {} y que significado tienen las llaves en si? Vi en algunos códigos que algunas veces usan {} en variables y no entiendo su utilidad al respecto. En funciones o procedimientos se pueden usar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Porque no puedo usar ReDim en un array irregular?
>
> ```
> ReDim mat((4)()) //Error
> ```

Sí se puede. Es solo que no lo estás haciendo de la forma correcta. Debería ser:

```
ReDim mat(4)
```

---

> por qué no tiran error cuando uso los {}
>
> ```
> mat = New Integer(1)() //Error
> mat = New Integer(1)() {}
> mat2 = New Integer(4, 2) //Error
> mat2 = New Integer(4, 2) {}
> ```

Simplemente porque la sintaxis para crear un array usando `New` **siempre** requiere que incluyas los `{}`. No se pueden omitir.

Estoy de acuerdo que, a primera vista, es difícil entender porque la sintaxis te obliga a incluir los `{}` para asignar un array multi-dimensional o un array de un array. Pero se entiende mejor si consideramos el caso más común, un arreglo normal.

Por ejemplo, digamos que tienes una clase sencilla definida de esta manera (nota el constructor que acepta un valor numérico):

```
Public Class MiClase
   Public Sub New(n As Integer)

   End Sub
End Class
```

Entonces, la pregunta es, si el asignar un arreglo con `New` no requiere los `{}`, ¿cómo se debe interpretar la sentencia siguiente?

```
miVariable = New MiClase(10) '???
```

¿Estoy tratando de crear una instancia de `MiClase` usando el constructor que acepta un valor numérico? O, ¿estoy tratando de asignar un nuevo arreglo de `MiClase`? Es ambiguo.

Es justamente para evitar este tipo de ambiguidades que la sintaxis de VB.NET exige los `{}` a la hora de asignar un nuevo arreglo con el `New`.

---

> y que significado tienen las llaves en si?

Los `{}` no solo sirven para aclarar que estás asignando un array, como expliqué ariba, sino que también es donde, de forma opcional, puedes asignar los valores iniciales para el arreglo.

Por ejemplo:

```
Dim miArray() As Integer
miArray = New Integer(1) {}
```

... asigna un array de `Integer` con 2 elementos. Y como no especificas ningún valor inicial, los 2 elementos quedan a cero, el valor por defecto para un `Integer`.

Pero, si en cambio, modificas la sentencia de la forma siguiente:

```
Dim miArray() As Integer
miArray = New Integer(1) {10, 20}
```

... también asigna un array de `Integer` con 2 elementos. Pero, esta vez, el primer elemento queda inicializado a `10`, y el segundo a `20`.

El mismo principio se puede usar con arrays mas complejos para inicializar sus valores.

Para más información: [Matrices en Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/wak0wfyt.aspx).